# mvvm light Messenger.Default.Register in View codebehind?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, mvvm, mvvm-light

The **BookShelf** solution **John Papa** presented at **Mix11** has something that sounds a bit odd to me...
It uses an **MVVM** pattern and **MVVM Light toolkit**... Everything is great.
The only thing **I can't understand** is this:
**In codebehind of Views it register for a couple of messages**, here it is the code:

```
public partial class BookView : Page
{
    public BookView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //btnEdit.SetBinding(Button.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("User.IsAuthenticated") { Source = Application.Current.Resources["WebContext"] });
        Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;
        RegisterMessages();
    }

    private void RegisterMessages()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<LaunchEditBookMessage>(this, OnLaunchEditBook);
        Messenger.Default.Register<SavedBookDialogMessage>(this, OnSaveBookDialogMessageReceived);
    }

    private void OnLaunchEditBook(LaunchEditBookMessage msg)
    {
        var editBook = new EditBookWindow();
        editBook.Show();
    }

    private void OnSaveBookDialogMessageReceived(SavedBookDialogMessage msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg.Content, msg.Caption, msg.Button);
    }
//...
```

It is a **business application**, if you switch from that Page to another and then come back there, **the page gets instanciated again and keeps registering** for those messages causing those to **fire multiple times**...

**How comes** it subscribe for those messages in codebehind instead of in ViewModels? has this something to do with UI thread? **Is this a correct implementation?

**How would you unregister those messages if user navigates to another page?**

**EDIT:** REFACTORED CODE

**XAML**

```
<sdk:Page Loaded="Page_Loaded" Unloaded="Page_Unloaded">
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterMessages();
    }

    private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug in his example.  He probably isn't expected the page to get instantiated more than once in an application.  There is a method for `Messenger.Default.Unregister` you could hook into on an Unloaded event to fix this issue (you might consider moving the register to `Loaded` as well.

I understand why he put the events in the View, however.  He is opening a new window and calling MessageBox.Show(), since these are very tightly coupled to the View, he kept them in the View.  I still don't like the solution personally...

Other MVVM frameworks fight this problem a little better, such as [Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/).  It has lots of helper classes to do View-like things from your ViewModel.  Caliburn can 100% eliminate anything in code-behind, but it has a pretty big learning curve.

Comment: This is why we use Caliburn at my work, but Caliburn.Micro might be a good option for you: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/.  I also have an MVVM framework here: http://nomvvm.codeplex.com/ but it is in the process of merging with another one here: http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageMVVM